# Custom bibstyle using jabref (Custom export filters)

Tags: jabref

I have a lot of articles and books in my `jabref` and connected it with latex using:

```
\bibliography{./Literatur/lit}
```

In "Literatur" folder I have 3 `BibtexFile` files: (lit.bib), lit.bib.bak, lit.bib.sav

Now I want to change my literature file. Currently all authors with all names and last names are included (in capital letters). I read [here](https://docs.jabref.org/import-export/export/customexports) that I need custom exports, but I cannot export to a `BibTex` File using those. The main supported export layout format seems to be *.rtf which I cannot read in latex.

Thus I found [rtf2latex2e](https://sourceforge.net/projects/rtf2latex2e/) webpage which says it converts the files.... But it does not work properly.

Any ideas how I can use a custom filter in my latex literature using `jabref`?

Comment: It is unclear, what you want. Do you want to export your whole `.bib` from JabRef or do you want to change the bibliography style in your current latex document?

Comment: I just want to change the literature style in my latex (e.g. no capital letters as authors....). The only way I know of is using export whole bib from JabRef.... If there is another way that would be also great! :)

Comment: JabRef is only an Editor for the bibtex database (in your case: `lit.bib`). The export function converts the database to othe formats. To properly use it with latex, you have to use citation commands like `\cite` and you can control the output by specifying a `\bibliographystyle`. You might want to read an introduction to bibtex, like this one: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Bibliography_management_in_LaTeX

Comment: If you have more specific questions, you should provide a [MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4408/29873)